# Как посмотреть разработанный мною сайт на мобильном телефоне из его папки?

Tags: html, android, веб-программирование

разработала простенький сайт. лежит у меня на компе в папочке, все как полагается. на компе (виндоуз, браузер - гугл хром) сайт открывается без проблем.

перекинула эту же папку себе в телефон (андроид, браузер - гугл хром) и, когда нажимаю на index.html, загружается только html-разметка. ни фонов, ни картинок. папку перекинула так же полностью всю, со всеми входящими.

как сделать так, чтоб я свой локальный сайтец могла просмотреть у себя на телефоне? соответственно без загрузки его в интеренет, только с папки. и вообще, такое возможно? (думала без проблем, как и на компе будет)

Comment: и это мне не для того чтобы посмотреть как мобильная версия будет отображаться, а тупо другу показать, чтоб комп с собой не тащить)

Comment: Покажите, как в HTML вы ссылаетесь на стили CSS? И как ссылаетесь на картинки? [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1172191/edit) вопрос, добавьте код прямо в вопрос.

Comment: У вас сайт это одна страничка или страничек много?

Comment: Какой не будь  live сервер, очень удобно им пользоваться, можно смотреть на любых  смартфонах планшетах и на любых компьютерах и наутбуках...

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите.

Нужно немного теории. я её разбил на шаги.

1. Когда Вы разрабатываете сайт на компьютере - то можно просто открывать файл в барузере. В этом случае браузер открывает файл так же, как он открыл какой то другой поддерживаемый не-сетевой формат, например, PDF. На этом этапе никакого клиент - сервера еще нет. И в адресной строке барузер написано что то типа `file://c:\project\index.html`
2. на скорее всего, вы разрабатывая даже сайт на компьютере пользуетесь каким то инструментом типа VSC + LiveServer (это такое расширение VSC). Ну, не в блокноте вы же его разрабатываете :-) На этом шаге у Вас уже есть клиент - сервер, а строка барузера выглядит примерно как `http://127.0.0.1:5500/www/index.html`

На этом шаге у Вас всё уже как в интернет, только интернет очень маленький: это Ваш собственный компьютер. Но если он в локальной сети - то с соседнего домашнего компьютера уже можно увидеть Ваш сайт. Есть небольшие технические трудности (типа firewall), но они преодолимы

3. Как только есть клиент-сервер - Ваш сайт можно показывать! Для этого - правильно, нужно "проковырять дырочку" в интернет. Для этого нужно или немного пошаманить с роутером, который даёт выход в интернет, или - что проще - поспользоваться сервисами. Мне нравится ngrok - [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com)

Думаю, теперь Вы разберетесь, как "временно опубликовать сайт" - принцип и ключевые слова вы знаете, остальное можно загуглить и заютьюбить

Успехов!

Comment: heroku ????????

Comment: Автор спрашивает "как посмотреть сайт локально без загрузки в интернет", а вы пишете про публикацию сайта, похоже это не то, что нужно автору.

Comment: Ну, к сожалению, сделать то, о чем автор спрашивает, без публикации сайта-невозможно. Просто "публикация" при разработке происходила автоматически, независимо от воли автора вопроса. Поэтому я написал "теорию про публикацию" - чтобы было понятно, как это работает

Answer (score 0):

1. На компьютере откройте ваш сайт в Chrome, нажмите `Ctrl + S` и сохраните вашу страничку в файл в формате [MHTML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) (или MHT). Теперь разметка HTML, стили CSS и картинки будут все находиться в одном файле.
2. Скопируйте файл MHTML на телефон и откройте его с помощью какого-нибудь MHTML Viewer. [Поищите](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=mhtml+viewer&c=apps) в Google Play.

Я попробовал на простом примере, у меня была всего одна страничка. У меня она открылась без проблем (вместе со стилями и картинками) в первом попавшемся MHTML Viewer из Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант создать webview андроид или ios приложение, собственно в которое и встроить ваш простенький сайт с стилями и скриптами если такие иммеются.